# What can you do with a .crt file?

Tags: https

I have a .crt file that's used for a game, I was wondering what exactly this is used for? Could you possibly view traffic that's secured using this certificate through something like Wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

basically a .crt file is used as a security certificate which in your case would be used by the game to establish the connections with the game servers. It is written in ASCII format with  X.509 certification. There wont be any physical significance of the .crt file for you personally and viewing traffic with Wireshark might not be possible with just the .crt file.
Thanks

Comment: No, its not just the CRT file , there are other files needed as well for establishing a secure connection.

Comment: .p12, .jks file etc etc

Comment: No , its not private its just like the license and the security thing for the game to connect , its nothing big by which we can do any harm , its usual certificate file which we can literally download normally and even some games show there certificates in the game.